How to merge a set of square cells (2D) into minimum number of larger square cells?

How to merge a set of uniform cells (2D), into minimal number of larger square cells, plus un-merged cells?
The picture depicts a signed distance field (SDF) of a torus cross-section in 1st quadrant (SD <= 0). Those SDF cells (not refined) far away from the cross-section, are not interested, thus need to be merged into big squares as much as possible.
As you can see, I can manually combine those cells, with 1 big square cell (in red color) and 6 smaller square cells (in green color), and the rest cells (not refined) can not be merged.
Nevertheless, is there any particular algorithms to do this job?
Update 1: A much coarser base grind (5x2 vs original 25x8), and level 4 refinement of the cells around the cross-section. SDF of interior cells appears a bit messy.


I think you should define better the condition to merge cells (eg. distance). Do you want the optimal solution? Otherwise a quad-tree based data structure might be a good start.

@JérômeRichard As long as the base cells (not refined one) are merged into a larger square shape, it would be fine. Those cells that are far way from the level-0 signed distance, are only used to identify points contained, and a rough estimation of the signed distance from bi-linear interpolation is more than enough. Smaller cells close to the cross-section, are used for the accurate SD value computation, for points inside the refined cells.

Instead of using quadtreee, we can make a coarse  grid, and only refine cells that are intersecting with, or are very close to the cross-section.
